# Using $resource to send JSON back to server with angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm new to angularjs and working on a project and I'm trying to send JSONs back to a sever. My JSON contains string, and some arrays. The elements in JSON will be listed out and the user will be able to edit the fields and delete elements from the arrays. When they're done, they will click on a save button that will save the changes. I don't really know a lot about $resource so i might be approaching this the wrong way.

I'm input from the user and change the correct element from the JSON like so...

```
                <!-- date of birth -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="dateofbirth">Date of Birth</label>
                <input type="date" id="dateofbirth" ng-model="infos.Dateofbirth.Date">
            </div>

            <!-- Ethnicity -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ethnicity">Ethnicity</label>
                <input placeholder="{{infos.Ethnicity.String}}" id="ethnicity" type="text" ng-model="infos.Ethnicity.String">
            </div>
```

and then when the save button is clicked, i can send the JSON back with it's updated fields using a $resource call like POST. Is this a good way to approach this problem or do I need to do something different.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you've already [read this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), but reading it about five more times might help.  =]

It's tough to get a clear idea of what you're doing with the limited code snippet, but it sounds like a totally acceptable approach.  $resource also allows you to get something from the server.  When you do so, angular appends methods like .$save and .$delete to your objects so that you can modify them and then save them back without having to pass the object to the save or delete method, but if you're not doing a round trip that would allow that, this is a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 0):

As the $resource documentation mentions

> A factory which creates a resource object that lets you interact with RESTful server-side data sources

and you aren't really interacting with a REST API or Data. In fact, you simply want to pass data to the server. Why not just used [AngularJS $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) with a POST request?

Comment: I'm using $resource to get the JSON so I'm trying to be consistent. What do you mean by passing the data to the server? Like the JSON?

Comment: Consistent with what? What does $resource have to do with JSON? If you simply want to pass data to the server you can do this: $http.post('/someUrl', myJsonData).success(successCallback);